# Make use of an index file for parsing a large XML file

Tags: php, xml, indexing, xml-parsing, large-files

I'm working on a Wikipedia XML Dump file (15GB), which is provided with an index text file.. looking like this :

```
1628813:431:Bille August
1628813:434:Blues
1628813:435:Bioéthique
1628813:436:Brive-la-Gaillarde
1628813:438:Burdigala
1628813:439:Bouliac
```

The XML file is basically in this format:

```
<page>
<title> </title>
<id> </id>
<revision> 
    <id> </id>
    ...
    <text> </text>

</revision>
</page>
```

What I want is to get the Text tag content corresponding to specific page Titles.
How can I make use of the index file for quick parsing/searching to achieve this?

P.S: I already tried many solutions for quick parsing and nothing worked for my needs.. 
I'm working with PHP, I tried SAX parsing, which is quick but didn't allow me to handle the nodes the way I wanted, and tried combining XMLReader and SimpleXML, but it was too slow..

Comment: I don't know what you expect in terms of speed, but 15GB takes a while and you say XMLReader and SimpleXML were too slow?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois about 20s..

Comment: You can't expect a 15GB file to be read in 20s.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois the parsing stops because of the servers time limit, but even 20s is wayy too much.. So you're saying there's no actual way to quickly parse a 15GB XML file ? should I just find another way to acces Wikipedia content other than the XML dump !

Comment: Use `set_time_limit(0);` at the top of your script. If you think you can parse a 15GB file in 20s then you may need to wait another few years. I wouldn't be surpised if it would take at least 10 minutes until everthing is done. http://php.net/set_time_limit

Comment: @CharlotteDunois So there's no actual way to quickly parse a 15GB XML file. Anyway, thank's.

Comment: The is no way of quickly parsing ANY 15GB file.

Comment: how much memory do you have on your machine? do you have 32 gb of heap to throw around?